# creating a form rows and cols with flex

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to format a form to look like the image below using flex: [image]

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="user-info-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="flex-field">
        <label for="fname" >First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" class="firstname">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-field">
        <label for="lname" >Last Name: </label>
        <input type="text" class="lastname">
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row2">
      <div class="flex-field">
        <label for="Email" >Email: </label>
        <input type="text" class="email">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-field">
        <label for="phonenumber" >Phone Number: </label>
        <input type="text" class="phone-number">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label for="request">Request Details:</label>
    <div class="flex-field request">
    <textarea class="rdetails"></textarea>
  </div>
```

The above is the html code that I am using and I am having trouble styling it to look like the above using flex

Comment: Flexbox is not optimal here. Use a table or CSS-Grid

Answer (score -1):

Use an outer box with flex-column
Then make two new divs inside. The upper one with flex-row and the other one with flex-column again.
In the bottom one, you put in the text and the input field.
In the upper one, you put two identical (text differs) div with flex-column. In these two, you each put two div with flex-row and inside it the text and the input field.

Using tailwindcss you get something like this:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/lrP8uzlzkX

Hope this helps.